# How to get resultant HTML after executing all scripts in Java?

Tags: java, httpclient

I want to get whole HTML response entities using Java.
I have tried httpclient but failed because it doesn't attempt to execute Javascripts embedded in html pages.

What can I do?
Thanks very much!

Comment: Retagged, `java =/= JavaScript `

Comment: @Cerbrus This is a Java question.

Comment: @Cerbrus I think it should have been left as Java. I've rolled back.

Comment: Oh drat, removed the wrong tag of the two.
50/50, I always pick the wrong one :P

Answer (score 0):

It seems like [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) is the only choice if you do want to crawl contents requiring browser rendering.